# How to get bundle_path from rbenv setting in Capistrano deploy.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, rbenv

Since I have require `capistrano-bundler` and `capistrano-rbenv` gems, and have set as follow in deploy.rb file:

```
    # rbenv
    set :rbenv_type, :user
    set :rbenv_ruby, '2.0.0-p645'
    set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
    set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}

    # bundler
    set :bundle_roles, :all                                         # this is default
    set :bundle_servers, -> { release_roles(fetch(:bundle_roles)) } # this is default
    set :bundle_binstubs, -> { shared_path.join('bin') }            # default: nil
    set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }        # default: nil
    set :bundle_path, -> { shared_path.join('bundle') }             # this is default
    set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')             # this is default
    set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --quiet'                       # this is default
    set :bundle_env_variables, {}                                   # this is default
```

Clearly bundle_path is not in `shared` subpath, it should be `/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle`. **So how can I get that path after I have set rbenv's settings. I struggle for a long time but found nothing both on [github](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/) or `google.com`**.

Thx.

Comment: My guess is that you are getting an error of the type 'command not found', (either `bash: ... ` or `rbenv: ...`). Can you add what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

To get rbenv's gem path you can do `rbenv exec gem environment gemdir`.

However, I think the problem comes from the combination of the `:bundle_path`, `:bundle_flags` settings, and how bundler interacts with rbenv.

Because of the `--deployment` option (set in `:bundle_flags`), the installed gems won't install their binaries in rbenv's *system* gemdir, but on `app/shared/bundle`, so you won't get them in your `$PATH`.

To fix this, you need to add your command to both `:rbenv_map_bins` and `:bundle_bins` so that it is properly prefixed.

For example, for jekyll, you need to set:

```
set :rbenv_map_bins, fetch(:rbenv_map_bins, []).push('jekyll')
set :bundle_bins, fetch(:bundle_bins, []).push('jekyll')
```

This makes the command executed by capistrano to be something like

```
RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec jekyll
```

which will work because `bundle` is in `:rbenv_map_bins` and `bundle install --deployment` creates a `.bundler/config` file that sets the path to `app/share/bundle`